# Образование слов женского рода, соответствующих существительным мужского рода

Tags: морфология

Возможно ли образование форм женского рода у таких имён существительных, как *журавль, воробей, дрозд, грач, офицер, генерал, борец?*

Answer (score 2):

Такие слова (они называются феминативами или феминитивами) в русском языке без проблем обычно образуются в отношении живых существ с помощью суффикса "-их-" (журавлиха, грачиха, воробьиха и проч.), реже - "-иц-" (медведица). Часто они относятся к разговорному стилю, но само образование затруднений не вызывает.

Что же касается остальных ваших примеров, то они относятся к группе слов, обозначающих лицо по профессии (или должности). Тут надо различать феминативы, означающие жену представителя такой профессии и женщину с такой профессией. Первый случай важен более для исторического аспекта: генеральша, офицерша и другие обозначали жен служащих (в данном случае - военнослужащих), но не женщин такого звания, таких просто не существовало. Поэтому в литературном языке для женщин с такими профессиями как правило нет отдельного слова.

Особняком стоят слова типа "купчиха" и "врачиха". Оба могут означать как жену купца и врача, так и женщину соответствующего занятия. В зависимости от исторического контекста преимущественным выступает одно из двух значений ("купчиха" скорее именно жена купца, а "врачиха" - разговорное для "женщина-врач").

Я опускаю известные и в общем-то понятные случаи образований типа "учительница" или "машинистка".

И наконец слово "борец". Для слов с суффиксом "-ец" (боец, горец, кузнец, молодец) феминативы обычно отсутствуют. Отдельные случаи образования ("кузнечиха") или очень ограничены в употреблении или носят явно просторечный характер.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не возможно. Такие слова употребляются с прилагательными мужского рода и глаголами в форме женского рода (в прошедшем времени).

Answer (score 0):

Для некоторых из приведенных в вопросе существительных образование  форм ж.р. вполне возможно. Вот несколько примеров из нацкорпуса:

«― Налымов, Мишка, Мишука! В ответ лишь завозилась грачиха в гнезде в темных ветлах. ― Вот тебе раз, ― сказал Сергей, ― удрал. Ну, погоди!» [А. Н. Толстой. Мишука Налымов (Заволжье) (1909)]

«Воробьиха высидела маленьких птенчиков в шляпе, а тут дунул вихрь и унес шляпу вместе с воробьиным гнездом.» [Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк. Старый Воробей (1892)]

«Гнездятся, вероятно, на Острове. Журавлиха на яйцах. Журавль гнездует в глухом болоте, а пасется в степях, красуясь на длинных ногах.» [М. М. Пришвин. Дневники (1927)]

Кроме того, можно найти примеры, где журавлиной и журавлихой называют ягоду (клюкву), когда 
Журавлина становится женским именем, а Грачиха — женским прозвищем и даже топонимом (с. Грачиха).

А еще возможно образование форм ж.р. через однокоренные слова: борец – поборница, офицер (служащий) – официантка.

Официа́нт. Это слово, заимствованное из французского (officiant), одного корня с существительным офицер. Оба восходят к латинскому officium — «служба».
Происхождение слова официант в этимологическом онлайн-словаре Крылова Г. А.

Comment: Что значит "см." в скобках?

Comment: Для меня это тоже загадка. Но так выглядит цитата: https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BE/%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82

Comment: Опять же "генералка" – и репетиция перед премьерой спектакля, и большая уборка.

Comment: помета * (см.)* - как в вашей цитате - означает, что автор отсылает к предыдущему слову. В данном случае - к слову "офицер", каковую словарную статью  и предлагается "смотреть". При цитирование такие пометы можно смела опускать.